# Amalgamated product of finite cyclic groups is not abelian

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-presentation

I want to show that in general the amalgamated product of finite cyclic groups is not abelian.

Therefore, I define
$A := \langle a \rangle$, $H_1 := \langle x \mid x^2 \rangle$ and $H_2 := \langle y \mid y^4 \rangle$, and
$$
  \phi_1 \colon A \to H_1, \quad a \mapsto x \,,
  \qquad
  \phi_2 \colon A \to H_2, \quad a \mapsto y^3 \,.
$$

So the amalgamated product of $H_1$ and $H_2$ with respect to $A$ is $\langle x, y \mid x^2, y^4, x = y^3 \rangle$. Using Tietze transformation I get $\langle y \mid y^6, y^4 \rangle$.

Does this work or do I miss something?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you for your hint. So it is possible to set $\phi_1=id_{H_1}, \phi_2=id_{H_2}$ (then the amalgameted product is $\langle x,y | x^2, y^4 \rangle\cong C_2*C_4$) and the claim follows using your hint?

Comment: Surely $\langle y|y^6,y^4\rangle $ is abelian.   I'm lost.

Comment: Why not just do $\Bbb Z_2*\Bbb Z_2$, as a trivial special case of free product with amalgamation.

Comment: @john_psl1298 What is this $2$ at the end of your definition of $\phi_2$?

Comment: I can't make any sense of this post at all. What exactly are you asking? Does what work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computation of the amalgamated product $H_1 *_A H_2$ is correct.
But it should be clear to you that $H_1 *_A H_2$ is again cyclic, and therefore abelian.
(More explicitly, $H_1 *_A H_2 ≅ ⟨y \mid y^4, y^6⟩ ≅ ⟨y \mid y^2⟩ ≅ ℤ/2$.)